# ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) alway return granted

Tags: android, android-lvl, runtime-permissions

I use Android API lvl 23 in my application. When I check Camera permission, the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` always return 0 (`== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`)

I managed to change it from `ContextCompat` to `ActivityCompat`.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean verify(Activity activity, final String[] PERMISSIONS, final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ID) {
    if (underAPI23())
        return true;

    String[] denyPermission = new String[PERMISSIONS.length];
    int denyPermissionLength = 0;
    boolean shouldShowRequest = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < PERMISSIONS.length; i++) {
        int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS[i]);
        LogUtils.e(TAG, PERMISSIONS[i] + ": " + (check != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
        // ===== ===== =====
        // This always return true. :'(
        // ===== ===== =====
        if (check != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            denyPermission[denyPermissionLength++] = PERMISSIONS[i];
            if (shouldShowRequest == false) {
                boolean should = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, PERMISSIONS[i]);
                if (should)
                    shouldShowRequest = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (denyPermissionLength > 0) {
        if (shouldShowRequest) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, denyPermission, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ID);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, denyPermission, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ID);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My dependencies in Gradle build

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    //...
}
```

Updated: Permission call

```
if (PermissionGrant.verify(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, GRANT_TAKE_PHOTO)) {
    // Do my jobs
}
```

Comment: What are you passing in as `PERMISSIONS`?

Comment: `PERMISSIONS[i]` whats in it ?

Comment: add PERMISSIONS in question

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your permission should be `Manifest.permission.<Android permission>`
What is your Android target version? `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` always return `false` that mean `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)` always return false at Android API lvl under 23 too.

[Document here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request). Please focus on:

> Note: If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose the Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog, this method returns false. The method also returns false if a device policy prohibits the app from having that permission.

Comment: Let me check that! Thank U.

Comment: It work for me but I used Linphone Library. It's not support API lvl 23. Do you have any exp about that?

Comment: You are welcome! I don't have any exp about Linphone Service.